# How to use Inkstitch with Inkscape?

Tags: zip, extract, gdebi, opt

I am; a new newbie. How do I actually open "inkstitch"?
I have attempted install/reinstall of both Inkscape and Inkstitch, for 2 weeks. (Ubuntu 21.10)
I am able to find user extensions & the downloaded icon for the file but there is no "install Inkstitch extensions".

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely using the snap version of inkscape, which is not compatible with extensions like inkstitch.

First, replace the snap version with apt.

```
sudo snap remove inkscape
sudo apt install inkscape
```

---

For Ubuntu 20.04, you need to update to the latest version of Inkscape with the official [Inkscape PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Einkscape.dev/+archive/ubuntu/stable).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:inkscape.dev/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install inkscape
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

---

Then, install `inkstitch`

```
wget https://github.com/inkstitch/inkstitch/releases/latest/download/inkstitch_2.1.2_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./inkstitch_2.1.2_amd64.deb
```

Now Ink/Stitch shows up in `Extensions -> Ink/Stitch`

[image: inkstitch]

Comment: Thank You I will learn at some point. unsupported file?

Comment: @juice Sorry, I did not understand what you meant.

Comment: Although, I have found that the inkSTitch files, which are dependencies, are in the root but locked. 

Gdebi: Doesn't seem to unlock them as I install. Using Gdebi to install the inkSTitch package,those files are listed but details show them as "lintianerrors.

I hope you can understand this, it is like "writing in another language" maybe Greek to me.

Comment: To install InkStitch, download the deb package, save it in the home folder, and run `sudo apt install ./inkstitch_2.1.2_amd64.deb`

Comment: THANK YOU I also have the same screen you captured, however, it does not have the needed files. I the smaller menu should list: Install InkSTitch extensions. I again have purged it form my PC.  The method you are suggesting has come back no such.

Comment: I don't know that. Contract the developers of inkstitch